# Llenar matriz en java de forma recursiva

Tags: java

Estoy creando un código que la funcion es llenar una matriz de 3x3 recursivamente, mostar la matriz y el resultado de la suma de los números de la matriz:

```
package matriz;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Rutina r = new Rutina();
        r.matriz(0);

    }
}
```

```
package matriz;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Rutina {

    int x;
    int y;
    int total;

    public int matriz(int num) {

        int[][] matriz = new int[3][3];
        if (x < 3) {
            if (y < 3) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese un numero"));
                matriz[x][y] = (num);
                System.out.print(matriz[x][y] + " ");
                total = total + num;
                y++;
                matriz(num);
            }
            x++;
        }
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);
        return matriz[x][y];
    }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que en la clase **Rutina** me da un error cuando en el segundo "if" por que no se llena la matriz correctamente y no sé como corregirlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolví el problema añadiendo unas variables "i" y "j" como contadores para poder salir del segundo if.

```
package matriz;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Rutina r = new Rutina();
        r.matriz(0);
        System.out.println(r.total);

    }
}
```

```
package matriz;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Rutina {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    int total;

    public int matriz(int num) {
        int[][] matriz = new int[3][3];
        if (i < 3) {
            if (j < 3) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese un numero"));
                matriz[y][x] = (num);
                System.out.print(matriz[y][x] + " ");
                total = total + num;
                j++;
                matriz(num);
            }
            j = 0;
            i++;
            System.out.println();
            matriz(num);
            
        }
        return matriz[y][x];
    }
}
```